# This basic C program alway gets wrong answer, especially x always be 0, value of y is correct

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char x, y;
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("%d %d", x, y);
}
```

for example:
I enter "3 4"
and it prints out "0 4"

Comment: `char x, y;` --> `int x, y;`.  Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: That should be int instead of char but even if this was intentional I dont know what platform and compiler your using but i compiled this with code::blocks and with linux built in gcc compiler with the basic `cc test.c -o test` command and when i typed 3 4 at the prompt thats exactly what it printed to me

Comment: What happens when you declare `x` and `y` as `int`s?

Comment: When I tried running the program, it crashed with the message 'Stack Smashing Detected'.  I think that `scanf`  and `printf` are trying to deal with too many bytes.

Comment: Do you happen to know how many times questions like this have been asked? If only you had spent the time to google "scanf wrong" or something, or better yet "scanf manual"...

Answer (score 5):

When the format specifier in a `scanf` is `%d`, the expected argument is of type `int*`. You are passing arguments of type `char*` when the expected types are `int*`. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if its necessarily undefined behaviour in C, it's just not desirable behaviour.  With only two `char`s its undefined (as far as I know), but if the program declared `sizeof(int)+1` characters and passed only the first two into `scanf` perhaps that would be defined (and undesirable)?

Comment: @ilent2, when a function treats a `char*` as an `int*`, the behavior is going to be undefined.

Comment: Isn't the cast fine in C (or is it only fine when casting something to `void*`)?

Comment: @ilent2, You can cast an `int*` to `char*` and back. That will be OK as long as the original pointer is a valid `int*`.

Comment: @ilent2: the behavior is indeed undefined per 7.21.6.2/10 of the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  The OP either needs to change the types of `x` and `y` to `int`, or he needs to use the `%hhd` conversion specifier.

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks! I should probably make sure I have a copy of the standard on my hot bar for times like these.

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting a user to type two small integers and display them, then change char to int so your code looks like the one shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("%d %d", x, y);
}
```

Replace `int x, y;` with `long x, y;` if you expect to use numbers larger than a few digits.

This program however won't work well with strings or numbers with decimals.

Comment: If replacing with `long` then use `%ld` as format specifier in all cases

Answer (score 1):

The type of the object and the conversion specifier have to match, or the behavior is undefined.  Here's a short list of conversion specifiers and the types they expect:

```
Conversion Specifier        Type
--------------------        ----
                  %d        int *
                 %hd        short *
                %hhd        char * (when reading a numeric value to char type)
                 %ld        long *
                %lld        long long *

                  %u        unsigned *
                 %hu        unsigned short *
                %hhu        unsigned char *
                 %lu        unsigned long *
                %llu        unsigned long long *
```

Hopefully you notice the pattern.  This list only covers signed and unsigned decimal integers; refer to 7.21.6.2 of the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or check your handy C reference manual for a complete list of conversion specifiers and the types they expect.

Comment: I think you should add that the table applies for `scanf` (and related functions) and not for `printf` (and related functions)